# Know the component that called a function

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to dynamically create UI elements such as: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html
based on JSON data.

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  onValueChange={(lang) => this.setState({language: lang})}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

Using this boilerplate I see two problems:

First: I cannot distinguish between the Picker component that called the method. Is there a way in JavaScript to know which component called a certain function? (I am a JS noob and could not find anything helpful about this)

Second: The selectedValue property is bound to the state. How would I go about doing this in my case where I create Picker elements on the fly. I do not want to explicitly call each component and update this property but the way it works now is not great. Removing this property does not display the last selected item but the topmost in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to keep state for each value for each `<Picker>` component. There are multiple ways of doing that. One way is:

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.picker1}
  onValueChange={(lang) => {
    let state = this.state;
    state['picker1'] = val;
    this.setState(state);
  }}>
  <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
  <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
</Picker>
```

**Example code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View, 
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';

export default class DemoProject extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  _renderInputs() {
    const inputCount = 4;
    const inputs = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < inputCount; i++) {
      const stateValueIdentifier = 'text' + i;
      inputs.push(
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputStyle}
          key={'text-input-' + i}
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            let state = this.state;
            state[stateValueIdentifier] = text;
            this.setState(state)
          }}
          value={this.state[stateValueIdentifier]}
        />
      )
    }
    return inputs;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>test</Text>
        {this._renderInputs()}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  inputStyle: {
    height: 40, 
    borderColor: 'gray', 
    borderWidth: 1, 
    flex: 1
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('DemoProject', () => DemoProject);
```

Comment: I am creating these components dynamically. I don't know how many there will be. This solution is similar to the boilerplate code and does not solve my problem.

Comment: When you create them you need to define a state variable for which you can use. State variables can be created dynamically so I don't see why you can't use this approach.

Comment: I am creating them based on a JSON file using conditional rendering. Creating the state variables I cannot do in the render loop. So I believe I'd have to parse the JSON first, create the state variables for your solution?

Comment: I have updated my example with actual code that renders TextInput dynamically. Should work with you JSON file as well.

Comment: Oh I see. This was a classic case of somebody not fully understanding the react concepts yet. I could adopt the solution for my case. Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: No worries @Alex happy coding!